# Is there a standard way of Watermarking videos in Python?

Tags: python, video-processing, watermark, video-watermarking

Is there any standard method of watermarking videos of some format in Python?

And how about still images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest checking out [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) or [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/), but that's about as good as it gets.  Try to find a way to leverage ffmpeg proper if you can.

For still images, simply use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), the Python Imaging Library.

Answer (score 0):

Transloadit provides image & video conversion via web services, works well, and very cheap.  If you need to do this on a large scale and don't want to buy a bunch of HW, they are great. Someone mentioned Zencoder.  I don't have experience to understand all the tradeoffs between Transloadit and Zencoder.  However in their current pricing models, Transloadit charges per GB of video and Zencoder charges per minute of video.  If you are doing enough volume to worry about scalable pricing, for the scenarios I've looked at, Transloadit is cheaper for smaller / lower-resolutions videos.  Perhaps obviously :)

Comment: Be careful with Transloadit. The service is buggy and support requests seem to go unanswered.

Comment: I'm a Transloadit co-founder. Where do you get this information from? We've had some trouble in the beginning but are running very solid now and we always address our support requests swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a robust (for-pay) service, I've had a very nice experience with Zencoder. The python api module is easy to use and fairly well documented.